# Crystal Reports Crosstab Summarized Fields labels not aligned

Tags: crystal-reports, vertical-alignment, crosstab

I have been having trouble with the summarized field labels of my Crystal Reports crosstab aligning with their corresponding cells while formatting the crosstab.  There are multiple summarized fields per row.

I am attempting to mimic excel style using crosstab.  This may not be the best way to go about it but with the data and my crystal experience it has been my best option.  My steps have been to:

1. Uncheck "Show Cell Margins" in the Customize Style tab of Cross-Tab Expert.
2. Put a bottom border on the display cells and label text objects.

When I do this the Cells space out vertically slightly and look fine, however the Summarized Field row labels to the left of them do not space out but still grow with the cells; so the text objects that they consist of actually overlap, while the cells do not.  So now the Labels do not align with the Cells themselves.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/655zj.jpg - Default Crosstab formatting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJlPW.jpg - After applying the formatting steps from above.

Sorry for the long explanation.  I have tried everything I could think of to re-align them but have come up blank.  If you have any suggestions please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: not sure why but try to drag the header cells down to re align with the data cells

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't mention it but I did try that, it just increased the cell size accordingly and didn't realign.

Comment: How are you performing step #2 (adding the bottom border line)?

Comment: I am adding a border to the Cell itself. When I do this it carries the formatting over to all horizontal cells for the same summary. I am adding it to the bottom of each cell to have a single line seperating each row.  Sorry about the slow response.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the formatting of a summarized field by clicking embedded object formats. Like right click on one of the Summarized field and then click Format Object, from Here you can format a particular summarized field.